# converting NDB Datetimeproperty to date

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, app-engine-ndb

I have a NDB datetime property stored on Google App Engine.  I'm trying to query for all records since yesterday by converting the datetime to a date, then filtering the query for anything greater or equal to yesterdays date.  However, I am getting the following error:

```
follower_trans = fol.query(
    datetime.datetime.date(fol.followed_date) >= self.yesterday).fetch()
```

`TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'DateTimeProperty'`

If i use just `datetime.date()` it sends an error requiring an integer as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

`fol.followed_date` is the model's property, not an entity's value.  You cannot convert a *property* to a date, as it has no value.  You need to fix the query constructor:

```
follower_trans = fol.query(fol.followed_date >= self.yesterday).fetch()
```

(assuming you've created self.yesterday as a datetime object.)

Also, it is proper to use a capital letter for any Class names.  Should have been:

```
class Fol(ndb.Model):
    followed_date =  ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

and

```
Fol.query(Fol.followed_date >= self.yesterday).fetch()
```

Comment: When I try fol.followed_date.date(), I get this error: AttributeError: 'DateTimeProperty' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: The problem is your are using the property and not the value.  Your query should be something like `fol.query(followed_date >=self.yesterday).fetch()`  fol.followed_date is the model's property, not the entity's date.

Comment: Technically the query should be `Fol.query(Fol.followed_date >= self.yesterday)` This assumes that `yesterday` is in fact a datetime. If it's a date you will probably need to convert it to a datetime first.

Comment: Yes, the error comes from trying to convert the *property* `fol.followed_date` to a date object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a conversion as part of the query, so you'll have to create 'yesterday' as a datetime and filter using that.